# Return function for list of id's

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have method that returns function for companySurveys

Here is it

```
private Func<IQueryable<Client>, IQueryable<CompanySurvey>> JoinCompanySurvey(int id, 
        IQueryable<CompanySurvey> companuSurveyQuery)
    {
       var function = (IQueryable<Client> companies) => from companySurvey in companuSurveyQuery
                          where companySurvey.Id == id
                          join company in companies
                          on companySurvey.CompanyId equals company.CompanyId
                          into res
                          from company in res
                          select companySurvey;

        return function;
    }
```

id parameter is companySurvey ID.

I need method that can work with list of id's.

So I can send here List and return function for many companySurveys

So same stuff as now, but for many.

How I need to rewrite this method?

Comment: `where ids.Contains(companySurvey.Id)` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this, change parameter `int Id` to `IEnumerable<int> ids` and in the func body change `companySurvey.Id == id` to `ids.Contains(companySurvey.Id)`

```
 private Func<IQueryable<Client>, IQueryable<CompanySurvey>> JoinCompanySurvey(IEnumerable<int> ids, 
    IQueryable<CompanySurvey> companySurveyQuery)
{
   var function = (IQueryable<Client> companies) => from companySurvey in companySurveyQuery
                      where ids.Contains(companySurvey.Id)
                      join company in companies
                      on companySurvey.CompanyId equals company.CompanyId
                      into res
                      from company in res
                      select companySurvey;

    return function;
}
```